# OffsetDateTime to LocalDate get different result on different computer

Tags: java, java-time

I have a offsetDateTime that I search to convert to LocalDate.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         
         OffsetDateTime billDate = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-06-12T22:00:00-04:00");             
         
        System.out.println(billDate);
        
        System.out.println(billDate.toLocalDate());
     }
}
```

On some computer I get
**2019-06-12**

and on some other, I get
**2019-06-13**

Java do an conversion depending of the time zone of the computer?

Comment: It's great that you have reduced this to a small snippet of code, but I fear that you may have reduced it more than intended. Do you see different output for _this particular_ snippet on different machines? If so, can you share the time zone set on each? I am seeing 2019-06-12 for all 664 time zone files on my machine: `$ ( for TZ in $(cd /usr/share/zoneinfo && echo */*); do export TZ; java So63041694; done ) | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: [`OffsetDateTime.toLocalDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toLocalDate()) “returns a `LocalDate` with the same year, month and day as this date-time.” So either there’s an error on your side or in the library. Not what you wanted to hear, but I consider one on your side more likely.

Comment: I have voted to close as unreproducible. If you edit the question and report that you have got a computer where you can still reproduce the error, either with the snippet in the question or with a different (minimal) snippet that you post, I will be happy to retract my close vote. You may also want to report which OS and which Java version that computer is running.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question as asked:

> Java do an conversion depending of the time zone of the computer?

**No.**

The documentation of `OffsetDateTime.toLocalDate` is clear enough:

> Gets the `LocalDate` part of this date-time.
>
> This returns a `LocalDate` with the same year, month and day as this
> date-time.

So you will always get `2019-06-12` from the code in your question, never `2019-06-13`, no matter the time zone setting of the JVM or of the computer.

I have also run your code on Java 8, 9 and 11 in Europe/Copenhagen time zone (where the corresponding time is 2019-06-13T04:00:00+02:00). I got `2019-06-12` each time.

**Documentation link**: [`OffsetDateTime.toLocalDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toLocalDate()).

Comment: Thank you for your the information. You are right, I will remove my answer. Found this that convincied me: "This class does not store or represent a time or time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone." at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the time in one timezone to the same local time in your timezone by calling `billDate.atZoneSimilarLocal(ZoneId.systemDefault())`

So that would be a way of approaching this sort of problem. But, like Chris in the comment, I can't reproduce your exact problem. `toLocalDate()` seems to me to do what I assume you want, and take the date part of your OffsetDateTime local to the zone offset you specified in it (not local to your own zone).